# Create Amazon S3 cloudwatch alarm in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to create a cloud watch alarm when an Amazon S3 bucket is created without any encryption in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** that is triggered on `CreateBucket`, but then you would need some extra logic (eg in an AWS Lambda function) to check the encryption state. However, it would not detect if the encryption is later disabled.

Alternatively, you could use an **AWS Config rule** that checks the encryption status of buckets on a regular basis.

See: [s3-bucket-server-side-encryption-enabled - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-server-side-encryption-enabled.html)